# Scala: how to efficiently intersect two sets taking into account element frequencies

Tags: python, scala

Consider the following steps in python:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> A = ["a", "b", "d", "d"]
>>> Counter(A)
Counter({'d': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1})
>>> B = ["a", "a", "b",  "d", "d"]
>>> Counter(B)
Counter({'a': 2, 'd': 2, 'b': 1})
>>> common = Counter(A) & Counter(B)
>>> common
Counter({'d': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1})
>>> sum(common.values())
4
```

I want to write the Scala equivalent of these steps. 
Since Scala doesn't have mutli-set I probably don't want to follow the exact path. (Or I'm not sure how slow it would be to use a third-party multi-set).
Scala `Set`s wouldn't work, because they don't keep the freq. But I can do a mixture of `Set` and a map to keep the counts.

```
scala> val A = Seq("a", "b", "d", "d")
A: Seq[String] = List(a, b, d, d)

scala> val B = Seq("a", "a", "b",  "d", "d")
B: Seq[String] = List(a, a, b, d, d)

scala> val AWordFreqMap = A.groupBy(a => a).map{case (k, v) => (k -> v.length)}
AWordFreqMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 1, d -> 2, a -> 1)

scala> val BWordFreqMap = B.groupBy(a => a).map{case (k, v) => (k -> v.length)}
BWordFreqMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 1, d -> 2, a -> 2)

scala> A.toSet.intersect(B.toSet).toList.map(i => scala.math.min(AWordFreqMap(i), BWordFreqMap(i)) ).sum
res2: Int = 4
```

Can I do simpler?

Comment: Was missing an import. Corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out @Psidom